# PHP mass file copy

Tags: php, batch-file

If I have a file called file.html how do i make 10 clones of this file via PHP such that they are renamed file1....file10?

```
$filename = 'file.html'
$copyname = 'file2.html'
if ($file = @fopen($copyname, 'x')) {
    // We've successfully created a file, so it's ours.  We'll close
    // our handle.
    if (!@fclose($file)) {
        // There was some problem with our file handle.
        return false;
    }

    // Now we copy over the file we created.
    if (!@copy($filename, $copyname)) {
        // The copy failed, even though we own the file, so we'll clean
        // up by itrying to remove the file and report failure.
        unlink($copyname);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Remove those @-signs that hides error messages that would help you debug your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small file approach: this allows you to do something with the contents of the file before saving it:

```
$text = file_get_contents('file.html');
for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    file_put_contents('file'.$i.'.html', $data);
}
```

Bigger files approach: this does not allow you to access the contents of the file before saving it, it only tells the underlying OS to make the copy (equivalent to a linux bash command of `cp file.html file1.html`):

```
for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    copy('file.html', 'file'.$i.'.html');
}
```

Comment: @file_put_contents('file'.$i.'.html'); // to avoid errors to be displayed

Comment: This will work fine for smaller file, but may cause problems for a large one.  What if your file is 300 MB?  I think using `copy` would be a better approach.

Comment: My M.O. is to address errors. Hiding them might make things worse in the long run so I usually check if i have write permissions in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

Just run your code in a loop:

```
$filename = 'file.html'
for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++) {
    $copyname = "file$i.html";
    copy($filename, $copyname);
}
```

Feel free to add error checking and handling.